# Good design practice concerning MVC view interface

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, user-interface

I don't often have to create GUI's but today I do so I was hoping for some design input.

Basically I have a backend which I intend to add a GUI too using the MVC pattern. The issue is I feel whatever class encapsulates the main GUI window is going to have A LOT of state (all of the sub elements); and on top of that it's going to have a lot of setters, and possibly getter, clear, colour, size, position and refresh functions too.

- One option is to march ahead with this idea and have a very large public interface which deals with the types the GUI uses (`std::string`, `std::vector<std::string>`...) the more control I want over the UI the more public member function I am going to need.
- The other option would be to pass the program state to the GUI and have it decide how it display it, I fear doing this would mean it would give me less fine detail control and would break down the separation of concerns and would mean any changes to the representation of the program state would require changes in the GUI too.

Any input on the matter would be of great help.

If it makes any difference this is a C++ gui using an ncurses abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like to me you've thought alot about the M and the V, but not much about the C.  The pattern should really be called MCV because the whole idea is that the controller IS the bridge between your model (data) and view (GUI).  It sounds like you need a controller with most of the functionality you've mentioned.

Simply put though, your model obviously should know nothing about display and your display (view) should not know how to access the model.  You need a controller that reads the data (model) and gives instructions to the display (view).  If you have user interaction within the view, the controller can interpret that and modify the model as necessary.

The idea is that you never have to change all 3, but if you change the model or the view, you almost always have to update the controller.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the controller does indeed the most work (in terms of "top level code"), it manipulates the model at at least owns the view. My question concerns how the controller should talk to the view. It just seems like if I expose a subset over every mutable element of the GUI interface then there will be little abstraction at all.

Comment: I think what you have said has helped, in confirming that I have a problem, and the only way I know how to solve it is by having a very large public interface for the view.

Comment: PS bare in mind, unlike say a webpage which is "refreshed" in one go, I want to update individual elements. So for example if I want to change the title I don't want to have to reset the background colour or something like that.

Comment: There will always be some coupling between view and controller, the more complex the view is, the more it feels like alot of coupling because indeed it is.  Don't get overwhelmed by trying to separate everything.  That's the idea, but after all, there must be some coupling of view and model.  There's even a word for that coupling -- Controller.

Comment: There must be communication between model, view, and controller.  Don't sweat that, just make sure there's no communication between model and view (without going through controller).  Usually the pitfall is adding controller functionality to the view.  Just avoid that.  I feel like you might be over-thinking this.

Comment: I think I am over thinking it, I like things to be done properly and in almost all other areas of programming separation of concerns is key. Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one alternative to the giant interface.  Instead of having a function that handles each thing (size, font, color, what-to-display, etc...) have a singular function that accepts a "role" and data that represents the role.  This requires some sort of wrapper that can contain multiple data types.

[QT's QAbstractItemModel Class Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) has a good example:

> QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int
>   role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const [pure virtual]

What that function will do is return the QVariant that represents the role indicated at the index provided.

The downside of this approach, is you have to know what roles exist, and what they do.  [QT's default roles are shown here.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)

Comment: This is interesting, I don't suppose you have an example of it's use?

Comment: @111111, Sure: [Simple Tree Model Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html). Specifically, the treemodel.cpp file has a good example in the  `QVariant TreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const` method.

Comment: So am I getting this right I might have something like   `my_view.set_role(TitleSetRole, my_data)` (where TitleSetRole is some form of enum and my_data is variant type)?

Comment: Yes, something like that would fulfill the requirements to do what we're talking about.  This has the added "extendability" of being able to add roles without modifying the existing interface.

Comment: hmmm I see why that sort of patter would be good in some use cases (especially where you might be dealing with different version of the class) I am not actually sure it would be a good way to go for me it just "moves" the decision making from the interface it's self to switching on an input parameter. Thanks you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have parts of the model able to instrument themselves:

```
class Model {
private:
    int value;
public:
    void instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter);
};
```

The `Instrumenter` manages the creation of controls. The model will tell it how it can be controlled and give it access to the data.

```
void Model::instrument(Instrumenter& instrumenter) {
    instrumenter.addRangeController(0, 100, 5, value);
}
```

Then for different input devices (e.g keyboard, touchscreen) you can create appropriate controls:

```
class KeyboardInstrumenter : public Instrumenter {
public:
    void addRangeController(int min, int max, int increments, int& controlled) {
        // create 3 widgets, up arrow, down arrow, and value
    }
};

class TouchscreenInstrumenter : public Instrumenter {
public:
    void addRangeController(int min, int max, int increments, int& controlled) {
        // create slider with min, max and increments
    }
};
```

Instead of passing in the `int` directly we could have wrapped it in a controlling object, to aid encapsulation.

Comment: Interesting, this is perhaps a bit over engineered for my needs, and probably would increase complexity rather than reduce it (of course this design is very generic which is good). Also I really don't not want my model to have anything to do with the way in which it's displayed.

Comment: Similarly, you can generate a view of a model in an independent way, allowing the model to inform the view that it has changed.